# Why can we require that the hyperdeterminant has integral coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, projective-varieties

Let $X=P^{k_1}\times \ldots \times P^{k_r}$ be the product of several complex projective spaces ($P^k$ is the projectivization of $\mathbb{C}^{k+1}$) in the Segre embedding into $P=P^{(k_1+1)\cdots(k_r+1)-1}$. The $X$-discriminant is the equation of the projective dual variety of $X$ in $P^*$. In the book of Gelfand, Kapranov and Zelevinsky the hyperdeterminant Det (of format $(k_1+1)\times \ldots \times (k_r+1)$) is defined to be the $X$-discriminant, which is a homogeneous polynomial. 
Now they say that this is determined uniquely (up to sign) by the requirement that Det has integral coefficients and is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Why is this so? Or more precisely, why can we require that it has integral coeffients?

Comment: "uniquely" only up to sign, right? (Good question.)

Comment: $X$ and its dual hypersurface are defined over $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, uniquely up to sign. $X$ and its dual surface are defined over $\mathbb{C}$. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your comment: the projective space is defined over $\Bbb{Z}$, and so is the Segre embedding.

Comment: The question is non-trivial and boils down to the elimination of variables - how do you know that the projection of something defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ is also defined over $\mathbb{Z}$. It is true, yet not automatically clear.

Comment: @Lev Soukhanov: in modern terms,  $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^n_{\mathbb{Z}})=\mathbb{Z}\cdot [\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)]$.

Comment: @abx this remark is about Segre embedding, right? I wonder what's the easy way to prove that dual variety is also over Z, probably checking that it is over Q due to Galois invariance and also checking that every reduction is good?

Comment: @Lev Soukhanov: I haven't checked the details, but I think you can define directly the dual variety over $\mathbb{Z}$. The composite map $\mathcal{O}_X(1)^{n+1}\rightarrow T_{\mathbb{P}^n}\rightarrow N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}$ gives an embedding $\mathbb{P}(N)\hookrightarrow X\times (\mathbb{P}^n)^*$, hence a map $X\rightarrow (\mathbb{P}^n)^*$, and the image is the dual variety.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.